# Apache Kafka: Exactly Once in Version 0.10

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

To achieve exactly-once processing of messages by Kafka consumer I am committing one message at a time, like below

```
public void commitOneRecordConsumer(long seconds) {
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = consumerConfigFactory.getConsumerConfig();

        try {

            while (running) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
                try {
                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

                        processingService.process(record);

                        consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(new TopicPartition(record.topic(),record.partition()), new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() + 1)));

                        System.out.println("Committed Offset" + ": " + record.offset());

                    }
                } catch (CommitFailedException e) {
                    // application specific failure handling
                }
            }
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }
```

The above code delegates the processing of message asynchronously to another class below.

```
@Service
public class ProcessingService {

    @Async
    public void process(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("partition", record.partition());
        map.put("offset", record.offset());
        map.put("value", record.value());
        System.out.println("Processed" + ": " + map);
    }

}
```

However, this still does not guarantee exactly-once delivery, because if the processing fails, it might still commit other messages and the previous messages will never be processed and committed, what are my options here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Original answer for 0.10.2 and older releases (for 0.11 and later releases see answer blow)**

Currently, Kafka cannot provide exactly-once processing out-of-the box. You can either have at-least-once processing if you commit messages after you successfully processed them, or you can have at-most-once processing if you commit messages directly after `poll()` before you start processing.

(see also paragraph *"Delivery Guarantees"* in http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/consumer.html#synchronous-commits)

However, at-least-once guarantee is "good enough" if your processing is idempotent, i.e., the final result will be the same even if you process a record twice. Examples for idempotent processing would be adding a message to a key-value store. Even if you add the same record twice, the second insert will just replace the first current key-value-pair and the KV-store will still have the correct data in it.

> In your example code above, you update a `HashMap` and this would be an idempotent operation. Even if your might have an inconsistent state in case of failure if for example only two `put` calls are executed before the crash. However, this inconsistent state would be fixed on reprocessing the same record again.
>
> The call to `println()` is not idempotent though because this is an operation with "side effect". But I guess the print is for debugging purpose only.

As an alternative, you would need to implement transaction semantics in your user code which requires to "undo" (partly executed) operation in case of failure. In general, this is a hard problem.

**Update for Apache Kafka 0.11+ (for pre 0.11 releases see answer above)**

Since 0.11, Apache Kafka supports idempotent producers, transactional producer, and exactly-once-processing using Kafka Streams. It also adds a `"read_committed"` mode to the consumer to only read committed messages (and to drop/filter aborted messages).

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#semantics
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-kafka-streams/

Comment: @ Matthias J. Sax thank you for your response, it makes sense. With the latest version of Kafka do you know if my consumer should still find an active Broker and find out which Broker is the leader for your topic and partition, and handle Broker leader changes?

Comment: You only need to provide a list of *some* brokers. It will find the leader automatically from there. Leader change is also handled automatically AFAIK -- however, you might get some Exceptions if this happens and thus, need to reprocess some data (since your last commit). See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+0.9+Consumer+Rewrite+Design

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax What is the real benefit we are getting with this `"exactly-once scenario"` as compared to enabling automated commit? Under what scenarios and case, this will help. As in my case I will have multiple consumers running on a different machine (each consumer running on one machine) consuming data from the same topic which has multiple partitions and I want to **eliminate the possibility of missing messages and also to reduce the number of messages duplicated during rebalancing**.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax While it may often seem feasible, but I guess it should never be relied upon because there are always caveats. Even with this pattern the consumer can't guarantee it won't reprocess a message after a failure. What if the consumer consumes a message and then fails before the offset is flushed to disk or written into database? If you write to disk/database before you process the message, what if you write the offset and then fail before actually processing the message? This same problem would exist even if you were to commit offsets to ZooKeeper after every message.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Receiving duplicate message is ok in my case as my system can handle it but I cannot lose data at all so wanted to see if this approach will give any benefit or not by managing offsets manually either on disk or on some database.

Comment: Exactly-once is important if your application cannot deal with duplicates and will compute a different result if there are duplicates. For example, if you count and you have duplicates, you count would not be correct. Depending on you application this could be a severe error.

Comment: I completely agree with what you are saying. If your application can handle duplicates using auto-commit will give you what you want -- you will not loose any messages. There is no reason to commit offsets to an external system (and doing this would -- as you mentioned -- not help to get exactly-once -- exactly-once is currently not possible with Kafka -- as stated in my answer.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I see so that means if my application can handle duplicates, then there is no need to commit offsets manually and I can rely on automatic commit by Kafka (by enabling the flag). With this automatic commit, **I won't lose any data at all** but there might be possibility to get duplicated messages (and if my system can handle it then it's ok). Correct? And I shouldn't even worry about using either `commitAsync` or `commitSync` methods as well and let kafka manage everything. And also where does offsets gets stored in Kafka? I am working with latest version of kafka and consumer.

Comment: Yes. Using auto.commit will commit message implicitly on `poll()` (the commit is for messages that got returned by poll() previously -- ie, the commit happens after messages got processed). This commit happens in an async way, ie, can get delayed what could result in more duplicates in case of failure. If you want to reduce the number of duplicate, using explicit commitAsync or even better using commitSync helps. Depends on you use case how many duplicates you want to accept. Of corse there is a slight performance penalty if you use commitSync.

Comment: Offsets are stored in in Kafak topic called `__consumer_offsets` -- this is no regular topic and only brokers can write to it on commit of consumers. See the extensive JavaDoc of KafkaConsumer for more details
https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html Also Confluent docs are quite extensive: http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/index.html

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Understood. Yeah I am thinking of combining commitAsync with commitSync. Will think about this later on. Thanks for the documentation, I see there are few things in the documentation which I am going to leverage in my code. In my application, I am using Long.MAX_VALUE as the poll timeout. Do you think this is ok for production system or should I use lower timeout?
In my application, I don't have anything else to do other than waiting so that's why I have set Long.MAX_VALUE as the poll timeout but if it is not a good practice, then I can set some lower value.

Comment: If your application does not no anything else than waiting for new data, using Long.MAX_VALUE is absolutely fine as poll() timeout.

Comment: Thanks understood. I have another question related to Kafka consumer design [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072666/how-to-run-multiple-kafka-consumers-on-the-same-box-independent-of-each-other). I wanted to see if you can provide some input/thoughts.

Comment: Not familiar with details of the old consumer... Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Kafka 0.11.0.0 has been just released, it supports exactly once delivery now.

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_11_exactly_once_semantics

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging

Comment: Note that the consumer can still read duplicates. So exactly once end to end still does not come out of the box for the consumer

Comment: @PragmaticProgrammer agreed but there are very well understood techniques that will yield exactly once consumption. For example most of the Confluent Kafka Connect Sink Connectors have had exactly once consumption support even in 0.10.x. They do this by storing offsets outside of Kafka and they write the message offsets transactionally along with the data writes to the target repository.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have write semantics instead of delivery. I suppose that's more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I think exactly once processing can be achieved with kafka 0.10.x itself. But there's some catch. I'm sharing the high level idea from [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/) book. Relevant contents can be found in *section:* `Seek and Exactly Once Processing` in *chapter 4:* `Kafka Consumers - Reading Data from Kafka`. You can view the contents of that book with a (free) [safaribooksonline](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/) account, or buy it once it's out, or maybe get it from *other* sources, which we shall not speak about.

**Idea:**

Think about this common scenario: Your application reads events from Kafka, processes the data, and then stores the results in a database. Suppose that we really don’t want to lose any data, nor do we want to store the same results in the database twice.

It's doable if there is a way to store both the record and the offset in one atomic action. Either both the record and the offset are committed, or neither of them are committed. 
To achieve that, we need to write both the record and the offset to the database, in one transaction. Then we’ll know that either we are done with the record and the offset is committed or we are not, and the record will be reprocessed.

Now the only problem is: if the record is stored in a database and not in Kafka, how will our consumer know where to start reading when it is assigned a partition? This is exactly what `seek()` can be used for. When the consumer starts or when new partitions are assigned, it can look up the offset in the database and `seek()` to that location.

**Sample code from the book:**

```
public class SaveOffsetsOnRebalance implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
    public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        commitDBTransaction(); 
    }

    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        for(TopicPartition partition: partitions)
        consumer.seek(partition, getOffsetFromDB(partition)); 
    }
}

consumer.subscribe(topics, new SaveOffsetOnRebalance(consumer));
consumer.poll(0);

for (TopicPartition partition: consumer.assignment())
    consumer.seek(partition, getOffsetFromDB(partition));   

while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
    {
        processRecord(record);
        storeRecordInDB(record);
        storeOffsetInDB(record.topic(), record.partition(), record.offset()); 
    }
    commitDBTransaction();
}
```