# How to commit offset after deserialization error? spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am able to successfully handle the deserialization error using the ErrorDesrializationHandler, but when I restart my consumer it again starts to reprocess all the failed messages due to deserialization.
As deserialization exception does not make it to Kafka Listener, how to acknowledge and commit the offset?
Thanks.

The custom error handler I am using:

```
class KafkaErrorHandler implements ConsumerAwareErrorHandler {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaErrorHandler.class);

@Override
public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
    doSeeks(records, consumer);
    if (!records.isEmpty()) {
        ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = records.get(0);
        String topic = record.topic();
        long offset = record.offset();
        int partition = record.partition();
        if (thrownException.getClass().equals(DeserializationException.class)) {
            DeserializationException exception = (DeserializationException) thrownException;
            String malformedMessage = new String(exception.getData());
            LOG.info("Skipping message with topic {} and offset {} " +
                    "- malformed message: {} , exception: {}", topic, offset, malformedMessage, exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        } else {
            LOG.info("Skipping message with topic {} - offset {} - partition {} - exception {}", topic, offset, partition, thrownException);
        }
    } else {
        LOG.info("Consumer exception - cause: {}", thrownException.getMessage());
    }
}

private void doSeeks(List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitions = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    records.forEach(record ->  {
        if (first.get()) {
            partitions.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()), record.offset() + 1);
        } else {
            partitions.computeIfAbsent(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                    offset -> record.offset());
        }
        first.set(false);
    });
    partitions.forEach(consumer::seek);
}}
```

EDIT-------

```
private void doSeeks(List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> partitions = new LinkedHashMap<>();
AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
records.forEach(record ->  {
    if (first.get()) {
        partitions.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()), new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset()+1, record.leaderEpoch(), "A"));
    } else {
        partitions.computeIfAbsent(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                offset -> new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset(), record.leaderEpoch(), "B"));
    }
    first.set(false);
});
partitions.forEach(consumer::seek);
consumer.commitSync(partitions);}
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Which `AckMode`?

Comment: Using Kafka 3.1.0, Spring for Apache Kafka Version is 2.8.1, AckMode is MANUAL_IMMEDIATE.

Answer (score 2):

With `AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, see

```java
/**
 * Set to true to commit the offset for a recovered record.
 * The container must be configured with
 * {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties.AckMode#MANUAL_IMMEDIATE}.
 * Whether or not the commit is sync or async depends on the container's syncCommits
 * property.
 * @param commitRecovered true to commit.
 */
@Override
public void setCommitRecovered(boolean commitRecovered) { // NOSONAR enhanced javadoc
    super.setCommitRecovered(commitRecovered);
}
```

on the `DefaultErrorHandler`.

It is not possible with `AckMode.MANUAL`; for other `AckMode`s, the container will commit the offset for a recovered record by default (based on `isAckAfterHandle()`).

**EDIT**

The logic to commit the offset is in `SeekUtils.seekOrRecover` (after the seeks).

```java
if (commitRecovered) {
    if (container.getContainerProperties().getAckMode().equals(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE)) {
        ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = records.get(0);
        Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsetToCommit = Collections.singletonMap(
                new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),
                ListenerUtils.createOffsetAndMetadata(container, record.offset() + 1));
        if (container.getContainerProperties().isSyncCommits()) {
            consumer.commitSync(offsetToCommit, container.getContainerProperties().getSyncCommitTimeout());
        }
        else {
            OffsetCommitCallback commitCallback = container.getContainerProperties().getCommitCallback();
            if (commitCallback == null) {
                commitCallback = LOGGING_COMMIT_CALLBACK;
            }
            consumer.commitAsync(offsetToCommit, commitCallback);
        }
    }
    else {
        logger.debug(() -> "'commitRecovered' ignored, container AckMode must be MANUAL_IMMEDIATE, not "
                + container.getContainerProperties().getAckMode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this worked thanks!
I set another DefaultErrorHandler and set the property to true, thought can you please help with where I went wrong with my custom error handler?
I have edited the question.

Comment: You are only doing the seeks; the logic is in `SeekUtils.seekOrRecover()` to optionally commit the offset of a recovered record (I added the code to the answer).

Comment: Hi Gary, I tried to follow the above code but I am stuck as the consumer completely stopped throwing the DeserializerException and is receiving some junk data. Can you please check where I went wrong? or can you provide a sample code for this? Also, what shall be passed in the metadata parameter?

Comment: Why are you also committing the offsets of the remaining records? You should only commit the first one's offset (offset + 1). And, why are you using a custom error handler?

Comment: Even if I remove the else block and only commit for the first record, I am not getting any exception/record.
I wanted to experiment a litter with custom error handler and understand also, that is why I am trying to do this.
With DefaultErrorhandler, we can handle all retires/recoverable/commits but I just wanted to experiment.

Comment: The `thrownException` is a `ListenerExecutionFailedException`; the deserialization exception is its `cause`. I suggest you look at the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` to see how it determines whether the key or value (or both) failed deserialization.

Comment: Gary's solution worked for me. Also, please be careful to not set `factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);`
when you create `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`